finding cordinate of detected objects in yolov8
I would like to know how to take out the coordinates of the detected objects on our data by custom trained yolov8.
My code:
!yolo task=detect mode=train model=yolov8s.pt data='data.yaml' epochs=20 imgsz=640
!yolo task=detect mode=val model='best.pt' data='data.yaml'
!yolo task=detect mode=predict model='best.pt' conf=0.25 source='.png' hide_labels=True hide_conf=True

There is just one class.
Thank you
I couldn't find anything.
